# X Frame options meta tag

Tags: css, html, meta

i am getting this error on browser console when using following meta tag.
**X-Frame-Options** may only be set via an **HTTP** header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside **`<meta>`**.

this is the meta tag i'm using.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" />
```

can anybody tell me whats the cause, as this code is not written by me. how can i remove this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error simply means that `X-Frame-Options` cannot be used in a meta tag. It only works when sent as a HTTP header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Disregard the error, it is safe. If you need this feature, then you need to send the header along the response.

By the way, the same can easily be achieved with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks clickjacking attacks. [XFrame Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent clickjacking using a meta element, instead of using X-Frame-Options you can use Content-Security-Policy like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-ancestors 'none';">
```